# Gradle cannot resolve dependency for spring framework uaa client?

Tags: spring, gradle, groovy, grails-orm, gradlew

I have just started using gradle, and facing same issue in multiple gradle projects.
 The dependency for **'org.springframework.uaa.client:1.0.1.RELEASE'**
is not resolved.
I checked and the repository used, contains the given artifact but still gradle reports an error like below:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve org.springframework.uaa:org.springframework.uaa.client:1.0.1.RELEASE.
```

I googled a lot and found similar problems being faced by others, but no particular solution.

Here [Gradle Discussion](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/failure-to-resolve-dependency-but-artifact-exists/17977) it is discussed that the problem maybe due to the 'relativePath' in the pom, which is not resolved by gradle. And that it might be a problem in the pom, and not with gradle.
But what is the exact solution at the present, or any work around to resolve this issue ?

 Note : 1. An issue has been open in reference to the above gradle discussion but it's still marked as un-resolved !!
2. The project I am trying to run are using a gradle wrapper 'gradle-1.0-bin.zip'
**EDIT 1**
I am trying to run the gormish project from [GIT](https://github.com/danveloper/gormish) and I have faced same issue in another gradle project for using gorm-stadalone [here](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/gorm-standalone-example)
The repository used is : 
`repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo name: "Grails", url: "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"
    }`

Comment: Which repository you think you use? in Standard maven repo there is the Minimum Version 1.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: Have you tried with a version of gradle from this decade? ;-)

Comment: Added details in the question. I am actually trying to use gorm standalone, and I found these examples at git (gormish and rimero solutions). The actual version used in the second project was 1.0.3.RELEASE, which was not present at the specified repository. So I changed it to 1.0.1.RELEASE, which was actually present there. But still the error !!